# Problems with generating normal maps

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk

I am trying to create a normal map from a model using 3DS max.
when i goto “Render to Texture” and press render, i get an image with red color.
In projection mapping, when i click on pick , i don’t find anything to pick. Can anybody help me create a normal map or tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The red in the render is caused because the highpolymodel intersects your projection cage, the reason there is nothing to pick when you press the pick button is either you not having your low-poly model selected, or because you do not have the model icon (which is a small grey sphere) selected, which filters meshes from the list.